# "make them widely used" and "lead to them being widely used"

Tags: meaning, grammar, synonyms, academia

I have two alternatives in an academic paper. The first is

> Additionally, the expressive logic foundations of ITPs lead to them
> being widely used

The other is

> Additionally, the expressive logic foundations of ITPs make them
> widely used

Somebody advises me to choose "lead to them being widely used" instead of the other.
However, I can not figure out the difference.
Could you give me some help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll posit that 'make them' (etc) are idiomatically often followed by a noun phrase, particularly with 'widely used'. 'Additionally, the expressive logic foundations of ITPs make them the most widely used protocols in computing.' (You didn't expand ITP.) You'd not say 'The need for greater mobility soon made cars widely used' but 'The need for greater mobility soon led to cars being widely used.' I think it's because it's people, not systems or cars, who are in ultimate control. People may be forced into a course of action, but they prefer to say they've been led down that road.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for your kindness! You give me a lot of help!